# how to avoid angular mat autocomplete field to be cleared when user hits the enter key in the field

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I use Angular 12 and I have search forms with multiple mat autocomplete fields.

I would like the user to be able to submit the search using the enter key.

However, when the enter key is pressed after making a selection in any mat autocomplete field, the autocomplete field is cleared.

How to get the expected behavior?

Sample form below:

```
                    <form [formGroup]="searchCourseFormGroup" fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center"
                    fxLayoutAlign.xs="start start" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayout.xs="column" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <button *ngIf="this.clearSearchForm" mat-icon-button fxHide.xs
                        (click)="resetSearchForm($event)">
                        <mat-icon color="accent">search_off</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-autocomplete #autoLearningPlan="matAutocomplete"
                        [displayWith]="this.utils.displayItemLabel">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestedLearningPlan of filteredSuggestedLearningPlans | async"
                            [value]="suggestedLearningPlan">
                            {{suggestedLearningPlan.label}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="this.learningPlanSelectorIsVisible" appearance="fill"
                        class="shrinking-mat-form-field">
                        <mat-label i18n>Learning Plan</mat-label>
                        <input fxFlex matInput formControlName="learningPlanSelector"
                            [matAutocomplete]="autoLearningPlan" i18n-placeholder
                            placeholder="Type text to filter Learning Plans">
                        <button mat-button *ngIf="this.selectedLearningPlan.value != null" matSuffix mat-icon-button
                            (click)="searchCourseFormGroup.get('learningPlanSelector').setValue(null);">
                            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="shrinking-mat-form-field">
                        <input fxFlex matInput formControlName="name" i18n-placeholder placeholder="Course">
                        <button mat-button *ngIf="this.name.value !== ''" matSuffix mat-icon-button
                            (click)="searchCourseFormGroup.get('name').setValue('');">
                            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <button type="submit" mat-icon-button fxHide.xs>
                        <mat-icon color="accent">search</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add type="button" to buttons which clear the fields, so they also submitted the form.
Adding this makes it work.